# jQuery / AJAX - send additional data together with file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am uploading files to the server using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : 'http://www.example.com',
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    data : formData, // formData is $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    type : 'post',
    success : function(response) {something}
   });
```

I would like to send additional parameters together with the file. Is it possible? If yes - how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send additional parameters, you can just append it to `formdata` like below:

```
var formdata=new FormData();
formdata.append('simpleFile', $('#file').get('files')[0]); //use get('files')[0]
formdata.append('someotherparams',someothervalues);//you can append it to formdata with a proper parameter name 

$.ajax({
    url : 'http://www.example.com',
    dataType : 'json',
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    data : formData, //formdata will contain all the other details with a name given to parameters
    type : 'post',
    success : function(response) {something}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
   var formData = $( this ).serialize();
    //$.ajax({}) //remaining code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize the form using the `FormData` object instead of only sending the file.

```
var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
```