# AJAX multiple upload using FormData()

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'd like to do multiple upload using `formData()` and AJAX. My AJAX successfully sent data to controller. This is my script:

```
$(".upl_user_document").each(function(i){
    regist_data.append('bill_doc-'+i, $(this)[0].files[0]);
});
                    
regist_data.append("data_ci",JSON.stringify(data_form));
regist_data.append("data_epicor",JSON.stringify(JSON_regist));
regist_data.append("<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>",csrfHash);
                
    $.ajax({
        url         : url,                      
        type        : 'POST',                       
        enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',                        
        dataType    : 'JSON',
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        cache       : false,
        data        : regist_data
    })
    .done(function(data){
        
        //SUCCESS                           
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         
        //FAIL              
    });
```

This script success sent data to the controller. But, I got `undefined index bill_doc` error in my controller. This is my controller:

```
//UPLOAD DOC                    
$my_upload  = $_FILES['bill_doc'];
$j_upl      = count($my_upload["name"]);    
$files      = $_FILES;

for($i=0;$i<$j_upl;$i++){                       

    if(isset($_FILES) & !empty($_FILES)){
        $name     = $files['file']['name'];                      
        $tmp_name = $files['file']['tmp_name']; 
    }

    if(!file_exists(FCPATH."asset/asset_form_signup/uploads/".$epicor_id)) {

        mkdir(FCPATH."asset/asset_form_signup/uploads/".$epicor_id, 0755, true);
    }

    $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH."asset/asset_form_signup/uploads/".$epicor_id."/";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $_FILES['bill_doc']['name']     = $files['bill_doc']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['bill_doc']['type']     = $files['bill_doc']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['bill_doc']['tmp_name'] = $files['bill_doc']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['bill_doc']['error']    = $files['bill_doc']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['bill_doc']['size']     = $files['bill_doc']['size'][$i];

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $this->upload->do_upload('bill_doc');

    }

    $response_array = array ( "insert_message"  => "SUCCESS",
                              "token"           => $new_token);

    echo json_encode($response_array);
}
```

Do I do some mistake? The AJAX show no error. Any helpis greatly appreciated

Comment: 1) `regist_data.append('bill_doc', upl_bill_id);
    regist_data.append('bill_doc', upl_bill_tax);` sends two values with the same parameter name. One of them will get overwritten. Is that a typo?

Comment: 2) `enctype     : 'multipart/form-data'` makes no sense. $.ajax doesn't have an enctype parameter

Comment: @ADyson 1.) I am about todo multiple upload and want to loop the uploading proceess in the controller

Comment: Other than that, based on an example such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110402/5947043 there seems to be nothing obviously wrong with your code.  When you say "data is successfully sent", do you mean the request doesn't fail entirely? But have you checked whether the request _actually_ contains the data you expect? As in, did you look in the network tab to see it?

Comment: `I am about todo multiple upload and want to loop the uploading proceess in the controller`...sure, but that wasn't my point. You're overwriting one value with another. They either must have different names, or you need to make it an array e.g. `regist_data.append('bill_doc[]'...`

Comment: Ah I see. I'll change my code a bit

Comment: @ADyson how do I count the file that uploaded?

Comment: Examine the structure of $_FILES when it receives the upload, and it should become clear how you could count them.

Comment: show your task with screen shoot please??